# Recurrence relation for $ I_n = \int_0^1 (1-x^2)^n dx $

Tags: integration, recurrence-relations

I'm asked to find a formula dependent on $n$ for $I_n = \int_0^1 (1-x^2)^ndx$

Integrating by parts I got that $I_n = 2nI_{n-1}-2nI_n$, then $(2n+1)I_n - 2nI_{n-1} = 0$.

I calculated $I_2 = 8/15$ and $I_3 = 16/35$

Given that, how can I find a general formula for $I_n$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the recurrence you obtained

$I_n = \frac{2n}{2n+1}I_{n-1}= \frac{2n}{2n+1}\frac{2(n-1)}{2(n-1)+1}I_{n-2}=\frac{2n(2n-2)}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}I_{n-2}$ and so on to obtain

$I_n = \frac{2n!!}{(2n+1)!!}I_0 =  \frac{2n!!}{(2n+1)!!}$

where $n!!$ is the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) function and I used $I_0=1$. Now you can try and prove this by induction.

Comment: Oh I see! That's nice! I appreciate it! This is even better and easier that I expected.

Answer (score 0):

$$I_{n}=\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^{2})^{n}dx$$
$$u=x^{2} \implies du=2xdx, dx=\frac{u^{-1/2}du}{2}$$
$$I_{n}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}u^{1/2-1}(1-u)^{(n+1)-1}du$$
It's but the $B(\frac{1}{2},n+1)$
So, $I_{n}=\frac{B(0.5,n+1)}{2}$.